# How to pass data from stateful widget to Dialog Box?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to pass the input taken from a user in stateful widget to the stateless DialogBox. I am a beginner and it is my first code.

the input will be taken in texfield in stateful widget and output will be displayed in Dialogbox

Answer (score 2):

mmm...Please try to read the documentation (Dart)

https://dart.dev/guides

Flutter is written with Dart, so this is where I would start.

Now, to answer your question, for your case in order to pass information to the Stateless Dialog Box, the easiest way is to use a constructor. Then when you invoke the Dialogue Widget, you simply pass this information into it directly.

Like So:

```
class StatelessDialogue extends StatelessWidget{

final String informationToPass;
StatelessDialogue({@required this.informationToPass});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return AlertDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
      content: Text(this.informationToPass)
      );
 }
}
```

**@required** is an attribute in Dart to indicate to the IDE, that this parameter **informationToPass** is required in order for the Dialogue Widget to work.